# How to make changes in shared folders between two Mac computers and save those changes?

Tags: macos, file-sharing, file-permissions

I have a follow up question to the question on how to share files between two Mac computers. I've gotten that far using the "sharing" option in "preferences". Now the problem is that the person I'm sharing folders with cannot make changes and save the files into the folders we're sharing. It says these are read only even though I've checked "read and write" for each of the folders. Anyone have any experience with this? Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebuild permissions on drive using Disk Utility